# Rails - Search for object based on association's value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I've got two models `Company` and `InsuredObject`. `Company` has_many `InsuredObjects` and the reverse `belongs_to`. Currently, I have a functioning search for `InsuredObject`(s) that returns all objects that contain the search input as shown below:

```
# /models/insured_objects.rb

def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    where("object LIKE ? OR insurance_type LIKE ? OR class_code LIKE ? OR information LIKE ?", 
        query, query, query, query)
  end
end
```

and:

```
# /controllers/insured_objects_controller.rb

def index
  @insured_objects = InsuredObject.search(params[:search])
end
```

Each `Company` has a `is_active` attribute. I'm trying to think of a way to search for the same thing but only return `InsuredObject`(s) that their `Company`'s `is_active` attrutbute is `true`. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're looking at an inner join I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all entries of `InsuredObject` from active companies:

```
InsuredObject.joins(:company).where(companies: {is_active: true})
```

In `joins(:company)`, `:company` is a name of association (in `InsuredObject` you should have `belongs_to :company`)

In `where(companies: ...`, `:companies` is a table name for model `Company`

Comment: Excellent! I was so close. I was using "company" instead of "companies". Thank you for your help!

Comment: One more thing. How do I then query those results? I'm using `where` on the results and it gives an error.

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: information: SELECT "insured_objects".* FROM "insured_objects" INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "insured_objects"."company_id" WHERE "companies"."is_active" = ? AND (object LIKE '%auto%' OR insurance_type LIKE '%auto%' OR class_code LIKE '%auto%' OR information LIKE '%auto%')`

Comment: I stored your statement into a variable and then called my initial `search` method from above on it.

Comment: So this means that you have column called `object` in both tables and when you refer to this column it is not clear which one should be used. 
To resolve this refer to the column with table name. e.g.: `insured_objects.object LIKE ...`

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Its actually the `information` column. Thanks!